# Service Control Policy - Prevent Root

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to prevent the root account in my AWS Organization from taking actions in all the other accounts in the organization so I was planning to setup a Service Control Policy to block the root account which is also recommended guidance from AWS.

Sounds good in theory but can't the root account just remove the Service Control Policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the root can remove the SCP, but it's still good practice to block root from operating on resources. This is a soft guard rail to remind people not to use root for this type of thing.

AWS has an example SCP [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_examples_general.html#example-scp-root-user).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "RestrictEC2ForRoot",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:iam::*:root"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```